# Question about the definition of Pointwise and Limit

Tags: calculus

$ f : A \to \mathbb{R}$
The definition of Pointwise convergence $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)  \hspace{0.5cm}(1)$$ for all $x \in A  $

It seems to me that this is similar to the limit definition.

So I thought the translation is

> $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ such that, $\forall x \in A, n > N
> > \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon \hspace{0.5cm}(2)$

However, this is the definition for uniformly convergence, and for pointwise convergence

is

> $\forall \epsilon > 0,  \forall x \in A,  \exists N$ such that,  $n > N
> > \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon \hspace{0.5cm}(3)$

Since the definition of pointwise convergence is just same thing of limit definition above (1), but why its translation is different? (I thought should be (2), $N$ is not depended on $x$ according to limit definition translation)

Comment: Who told you that that (namely, your (2)) is the  "translation" (?) of the defintion of pointwise convergence?

Comment: @Timbuc I know that (2) is not the definition for pointwise, but what I confused is that since (1) is just like limit definition,and limit definition is (2), why not pointwise definition is not (2) but (3)?

Comment: The whole point of pointwise convergence is that it only applies one point at the time so there is no $\forall x$ in the definition.

Comment: @Winther, but since (1) is also the definition for pointwise, isn't (1) just a normal limit definition but having the limit value replaced by a function ?

Comment: @Hobbit6094 (1) is not definition of pointwise convergence. It only says that *a sequence of points*, denoted by $\;\{f_n(x)\}\;$ converges to a point denoted by $\;f(x)\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc, Oh, I see. Can I say that  a sequence of points, denoted by {$fn(x)$} converges to a point denoted by $f(x)$ for every $x$ in the set $A$, then we say {$f_n$} pointwise convergence to $f$ on $A$. So this doesn't have much to do with the normal limit definition at all.

Comment: @Hobbit6094 Exactly, I think you nailed it now.

Comment: $f(2) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(2)$, and $f(3) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(3)$, etc, for every $x$, and this has very much to do with the normal limit definition (of a sequence of real numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the order of your quantifiers change for the definition of uniform convergence. The point is that pointwise convergence simply requires that for each $x$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$. For *uniform* convergence, yes, you have pointwise convergence, but you require additionally that the convergence is *uniform*.

What this means intuitively is that if you are given an $\varepsilon > 0$ and you want the distance between $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ to be smaller than $\varepsilon$, *pointwise* convergence tells you that each $x$ has its $N_x$ such that for all $n \ge N_x$, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon$. So essentially, the sequences $f_n(x)$ all get eventually $\varepsilon$-close to $f(x)$, but each at their own pace, a priori. This is captured in the definition of the pointwise convergence of $\{f_n\}$ to $f$ :
$$
\forall x \in A, \forall \varepsilon > 0,  \exists N \quad \mathrm{s.t.} \quad \forall n \ge N, \quad |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon.
$$
The fact that the "$\forall x \in A$" appears first exhibits the fact that $N$ depends both on $x$ and $\varepsilon$.

For *uniform* convergence, given a $\varepsilon > 0$, we want an $N$ such that **all** $x \in A$ satisfy $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$. This cannot depend on $x$. This is why the definition of uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ to $f$ is 
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \quad \mathrm{s.t.} \quad  \forall x \in A, \quad \forall n \ge N, \quad |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon.
$$

An example of a sequence of functions which converges pointwise but not uniformly goes as follows. Consider the set $A = ]0,1[$ (this is $[0,1]$ without the endpoints) and the sequence of functions $f_n : ]0,1[ \to \mathbb R$ given by $f_n(x) = x^n$. It is not hard to check that $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for any $x \in ]0,1[$. However, if I am given say $\varepsilon = 1/2$, there exists absolutely no $N$ which ensures that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$, because
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)| = x^n < \varepsilon  \quad \Rightarrow \quad x < \varepsilon^{1/n} < 1$.
$$
Therefore, all $x \ge \varepsilon^{1/N}$ will need to wait for $N$ to get bigger for $f_n(x)$ to be close enough to $0$.

Remark : when a sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$, we usually write
$$
f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n
$$
without any reference to some $x$. Of course, it implies
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)
$$
for any $x$ in the domain of the $f_n$'s and $f$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks a lot